# Using a Modal popup contact form, Is it possible to show a confirmation in same popup, upon submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a very basic php email contact page that is activated when the user submits from a modal popup window. Instead of redirecting to a "thank you.html" page, is it possible to populate the popup window with the 'thank you' message?

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
<!--Subscribe Popup Function, JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<style>
.reveal-modal-bg {position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #000;    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8); z-index: 100; display: none; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.reveal-modal {visibility: hidden;top: 100px; width: 80%;background: #fff;position: absolute;z-index: 101;padding: 0px;border: 0px;margin: 0px 10%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">Subscribe</a></div>
<!-- Subscribe Pop-Up Content -->
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
<form action="receiving.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email" value="EMAIL" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>          
</body>

</html>
```

Here is "receiving.php":

```
    <?php 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$from_add = "$email"; 
$to_add = "myname@mysite.com"; 
$subject = "New Subscriber";
$message = "Email: $email";
$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";

if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
{
    $msg = "Mail sent";
} 
}
header("location: http://www.mysite.com/thankyou.html"); exit;   
?>
```

And if it helps to see here is the javascript being used "jquery.reveal.js" Please note that I am very inexperienced with js and php. This code was my starting point and it is from here [Reveal JQuery Modal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin):

```
    (function($) {

$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
$('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});

$.fn.reveal = function(options) {
var defaults = {  
animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
}; 

//Extend dem' options
var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 
return this.each(function() {
var modal = $(this),
topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
locked = false,
modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

if(modalBG.length == 0) {
modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
}           
//Entrance Animations
modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
$('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
if(!locked) {
lockModal();
if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
"top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
"opacity" : 1
}, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
}
if(options.animation == "fade") {
modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
"opacity" : 1
}, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
} 
if(options.animation == "none") {
modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
unlockModal()               
}
}
modal.unbind('reveal:open');
});     

//Closing Animation
modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
if(!locked) {
lockModal();
if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
modal.animate({
"top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
"opacity" : 0
}, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
unlockModal();
});                 
}   
if(options.animation == "fade") {
modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
modal.animate({
"opacity" : 0
}, options.animationspeed, function() {
modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
unlockModal();
});                 
}   
if(options.animation == "none") {
modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
}       
}
modal.unbind('reveal:close');
});         

//Open Modal Immediately
modal.trigger('reveal:open')

//Close Modal Listeners
var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
modal.trigger('reveal:close')    
});

if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
modal.trigger('reveal:close')
});
}
$('body').keyup(function(e) {
if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
});

function unlockModal() { 
locked = false;
}
function lockModal() {
locked = true;
}   

});//each call
}//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Try making div transition within modal just with first-button's click, then ask confirm on next button's click.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way . After mailing the user redirect the user to current page(where your pop up was)

```
header("location: http://www.mysite.com/#mailsuccess"); //with hash at the last
```

Now in Jquery get this hash match it and fire the pop up

Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var hash=window.location.hash;

      if(hash==="#mailsuccess")
          {
     $('#successModal').reveal({ /* options */ }); //You can use same modal or different modal to show success message
          }    

      });
```

USING SIMPLE AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
<!--Subscribe Popup Function, JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<style>
.reveal-modal-bg {position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #000;    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8); z-index: 100; display: none; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px;}
.reveal-modal {visibility: hidden;top: 100px; width: 80%;background: #fff;position: absolute;z-index: 101;padding: 0px;border: 0px;margin: 0px 10%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('submit','#mailform',function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //stop default form submit
       var email=$('#mailform input[name="email"]').val(); //get email from form

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "receiving.php",
            data: "email="+email, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            if($.trim(html)==='success')
                 { 
                   $('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close'); //close current modal
                   $('#successModal').reveal();  //open success modal
                  }
             }   
            });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">Subscribe</a></div>
    <!-- Subscribe Pop-Up Content -->
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <form action="receiving.php" method="POST" id="mailform"> //give a id to form
    <input type="text" name="email" value="EMAIL" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div> 

    <div id="successModal" class="reveal-modal">
        Mailed successfully    
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

in your PHP remove header location

```
if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
 {
  echo 'success';
  exit();
 }
```

Comment: This works beautifully. One followup question... I will have many pages on my site and the subscribe function will be available on every page. If I have to, I will use the instructions you provided to guide the user back to the site's index upon 'submit'. Is there a way to show the 'Success' message on the user's current page without a general redirect?

Comment: You can use ajax to do the job. After ajax success hide current popup & show successModal popup.

Comment: Added simple ajax functioning hope it helps

Comment: yes between script in the head , in $(document).ready(function(){  // all code here });

Comment: mailform is the id of the form

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it looks great, thank you for pointing out the 'mailform' id. However, the 'submit' is still only returning a 'success' echo page. I tried multiple devices and browsers too just to make sure nothing was cached. Does this work on your end?

Comment: try <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script> instead of the one you used at top

Comment: <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> try this ,removed semi colon

Answer (score 1):

Here is a resource you can edit and use Download Source Code or see live demo here http://purpledesign.in/blog/pop-out-a-form-using-jquery-and-javascript/

Add a Button or link to your page like this

```
<p><a href="#inline">click to open</a></p>
```

“#inline” here should be the “id” of the that will contain the form.

```
<div id="inline">
 <h2>Send us a Message</h2>
 <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
 <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
 <br>
 <label for="msg">Enter a Message</label>
 <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>
<button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Include these script to listen of the event of click. If you have an action defined in your form you can use “preventDefault()” method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".modalbox").fancybox();
$("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });
$("#send").on("click", function(){
var emailval = $("#email").val();
var msgval = $("#msg").val();
var msglen = msgval.length;
var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
if(mailvalid == false) {
$("#email").addClass("error");
}
else if(mailvalid == true){
 $("#email").removeClass("error");
 }

 if(msglen < 4) {
 $("#msg").addClass("error");
 }
 else if(msglen >= 4){
 $("#msg").removeClass("error");
 }

 if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
 // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
 // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
 $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
 //This will post it to the php page
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'sendmessage.php',
 data: $("#contact").serialize(),
 success: function(data) {
 if(data == "true") {
 $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
//Display a message on successful posting for 1 sec
 $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
 setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
 });
 }
 }
 });
 }
 });
 });
</script>
```

You can add anything you want to do in your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Ya sure this is just add id to your form
like:

```
<form action="receiving.php" method="POST" id="yourformId">
```

user javascript function
don't use submit button user normal button like

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="beforesubmit()" />
function beforesubmit()
{
    /**open popup**/ 
    return false;
}
```

onconfirm of popup execute code

```
$("#yourformId").submit();
```

Comment: I am such a novice with js and php. Could you help by showing me how to use the code?

Comment: i have given most of code. at opening your popup show a div having confirm and decline button. submit form by my code on click event on confirm button on popup.